# How to retrieve map of objects from resource to another resource in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I am trying to create 6 virtual machines in 3 availability sets for a 3-tier architecture. The DB virtual machine will have two NICs each for network segmentation, and the DB virtual machine will only have disk configuration. I have created terraform azure resources as per the below using the nested map of objects.

```
locals {
  vms = {
    nodes = {
      app_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "app-poc" 
        "vm_num"  = "1"    
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "app-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
        }
        "as"  = "0"
      },
      app_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "app-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "app-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
        }
        "as"  = "0"
      },
      service_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "service-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "1"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "service-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
        }
        "as"  = "1"
      },
      service_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "service-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "service-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
        }
        "as"  = "1"
      },
      db_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "db-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "1"
        "as"      = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-1"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
          nic2 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-2"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/db"
          }
        }
        disks = {
          disk1 = {
            "lun"  = "0"
            "size" = "1024"
          },
          disk2 = {
            "lun"  = "1"
            "size" = "1024"
          },
        }
      },
      db_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "db-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        "as"      = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-1"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
          nic2 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-2"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/.../test-vnet/subnets/app"
          },
        }
        disks = {
          disk1 = {
            "size" = "1024"
            "lun"  = "0"
          },
          disk2 = {
            "size" = "1024"
            "lun"  = "1"
          },
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the terraform code create - Availability Sets, NICs, VMs, Managed Disk and Disk Attachment to Virtual Machine.

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "test-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "as" {
  count                        = length(var.availability_set_names)
  name                         = var.availability_set_names[count.index]
  location                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
  platform_update_domain_count = 5
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-poc" {
  for_each = {
    for vm in flatten([
      for vm_name, vm in local.vms.nodes : [
        for nic_name, nic in vm.networks : {
          vm_number    = vm.vm_num,
          vm_name      = vm_name,
          nic_value     = nic.vm_name,
          subnet_value = nic.subnet
          nic_name = nic_name
        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${vm.vm_name}-${vm.nic_name}" => vm
  }
  name                = "${each.value.nic_value}-${each.value.vm_number}-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value.nic_name}-${each.value.vm_number}-ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_value
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm-poc" {
  depends_on                      = [azurerm_availability_set.as, azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc]
  for_each                        = local.vms.nodes
  name                            = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}"
  admin_username                  = "pluto-admin"
  admin_password                  = "password@29"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids           = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id]
  size                            = "Standard_B2ms"
  availability_set_id             = azurerm_availability_set.as[each.value.as].id
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}-OSdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "RedHat"
    offer     = "RHEL"
    sku       = "82gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
# Create managed disk
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "db-data_disk" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm-poc]
  for_each = {
    for vm in flatten([
      for vm_name, vm in local.vms.nodes : [
        for disk_name, disk in lookup(vm, "disks", {}) : {
          vm_name   = vm_name
          disk_name = disk_name
          disk_size = disk.size
          vm_number = vm.vm_num
        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${vm.vm_name}-${vm.disk_name}" => vm
  }
  name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_number}-disk1"
  location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = each.value.disk_size
}

# Attach managed disk
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "attach_disk" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk]
  for_each = {
    for vm in flatten([
      for vm_name, vm in local.vms.nodes : [
        for disk_name, disk in lookup(vm, "disks", {}) : {
          vm_name  = vm_name
          disk_lun = disk.lun
        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${vm.vm_name}-${vm.disk_lun}" => vm
  }
  managed_disk_id    =  [for disk_key, disk in azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk : disk.id]
  virtual_machine_id = [for vm_key, vm in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm-poc : vm.id]
  lun                = each.value.disk_lun
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
variable "availability_set_names" {
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["app-avset", "service-avset", "db-avset"]
}
```

**Error #1** : Seems like the for loop is reading complete map of objects. `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine` - `network_interface_ids = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id]`

```
Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine (Subscription: "a94f0758-94a8-426d-a3b6-aec6e83b51de"
│ Resource Group Name: "test-rg"
│ Virtual Machine Name: "app-poc-1"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="NetworkInterfaceCountExceeded" Message="The number of network interfaces for virtual machine app-poc-1 exceeds the maximum allowed for the virtual machine size Standard_B2ms. The number of network interfaces is 8 and the maximum allowed is 3.
```

**Error #2** at `azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment` - `managed_disk_id    =  [for disk_key, disk in azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk : disk.id]`
`virtual_machine_id = [for vm_key, vm in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm-poc : vm.id]`

```
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 213, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "attach_disk":
│  213:   managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk is object with 4 attributes
│     │ each.key is "db_node2-0"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Can someone throw a light on how to retrieve the object values and read from one resource to another resource ?

**Question Update with new error:** Error 2.1 :

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 215, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "attach_disk":
│  215:   managed_disk_id    = [for disk_key, disk in azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk : disk.id if startswith(disk_key, "$each.key}-")]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk is object with 4 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "managed_disk_id": string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error1:
Select only VM's specific interfaces

```
network_interface_ids = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]
```

Error2:
you need to get a specific value from the map by key.
`azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk` created with `for_each`, so result is a map with `[each.key]` keys and resource as on object.

`azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment` attaches one disk (`managed_disk_id`) to one VM `(virtual_machine_id`).

So:

- add `disk_name` to each object in `azurerm_managed_disk` resource
- fix

```
managed_disk_id = azurerm_managed_disk.db-data_disk[format("%s-%s", each.value.vm_name, each.value.disk_name)].id
virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm-poc[each.value.vm_name].id
```

Comment: I am getting `There is no function named "startswith"` error. code change `network_interface_ids = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-app")]`

Comment: may be old version? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/startswith

Comment: Terraform version upgraded. Error 1 - Fixed :) Error 2 - Not fixed with same syntax.

Comment: added more to answer